# How do I scrape data being a login screen for different login names?

Tags: java, python, web-scraping

I'm trying to compile the results of my class from my college's results page ([exam.msrit.edu](http://exam.msrit.edu)).

The USNs for my class are from 1MS16CS001-100

Is there any way that I could go about writing a scraper program to enter different values in the USN box and gather data?

I am quite new to scraping but have decent enough exposure to Python and java

Any advice is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily a scrape, but you can use Selenium Web Driver to browse to the page and input everything for you. Selenium Web Driver can be found [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html).

Essentially, once it is installed you only need to instantiate the driver and then loop through a list of values inputting them as you go.

```
from selenium import webdriver
# V sets up browser. If you want to use chrome addtional setup required
browser = webdriver.Firefox()     
for i in len(100):               #loops to arbitrary amount
    browser.get("http://exam.msrit.edu/") #HTTP GET Request to page
    elem = browser.find_element_by_id('id') #This is an html id. Could also use name, xpath, etc.
    elem.send_keys("your string {}".format(i)) #sends up keys
    elem. browser.find_element_by_id('id) #id for search button
    elem.click() #clicks that element
```

The documentation on selenium is pretty good. http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html

This will open a actual browser and will take some time to load so  it will not be the quickest way to do it but it will work. You can even take screenshots.

Comment: Should also be mentioned since you said you can also use java that selenium webdriver is also available for Java and a variety of other languages. http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp